# GridView Xml Error

Tags: android, xml, gridview

Error  on the following GridView xml

**Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 
     'match_parent').
    - error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 
     'match_parent').**

```
 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/albums"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="148dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:listSelector="#000000"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match_parent`  is introduced in android 2.2.  If your program is built with lower version of android then those may not recognize what is `match_parent`. match_parent is same as `fill_parent`. Change match_parent in your code to `fill_parent` otherwise you can increase android build version to support `match_parent`. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html)

Thanks
Deepak